# Run-Time error- Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted

Tags: c, arrays, stack

The program aims to print all the entered integers that were stored in an array. It works fine and prints properly except that the program ends in a runtime failure.

I've tried inputting nothing and it actually works fine and exits.

```
// Alex Ruiztagle
// 3/26/2019
// Script to do operations on user entered numbers. Also I really hate primitive types. I spend more time figuring out the right one to use than I do writing the logic.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0};
    int inpt;
    int counter = 0;
    int stat = 0;
    printf("Enter some numbers \n");
    while (stat == 0) {
        scanf_s("%i", &inpt);
        if (inpt == -999 || counter == 50) {
            stat = 1;
        }
        else {
            arr[counter] = inpt;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nYou entered \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        printf("%i. %i\n", i + 1, arr[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

If I enter 7, 16, 45
It should print out

1. 7
2. 16
3. 45

It does this except when it's time to terminate the program it ends in 
"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted."

Comment: What size do you expect `arr` to be?

Answer (score 0):

as soon as `counter` is above 1, the code has undefined behavior because it is accessing beyond the end of the array `arr[]`

This results (at a minimum) with the stack being corrupted.

So when the program exits it is accessing that corrupted stack as it tries to return to its' caller.

Due to the undefined behavior, anything could happen.  In your case, a seg fault event occurs